# Evaluation of limit using squeeze theorem

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $f:(0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ be the function defined as $f(x)=\sqrt{n}$ if $x \in \left[\frac{1}{n+1},{\frac{1}{n}}\right)$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $g:(0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $\displaystyle \int_{x^2}^{x} \sqrt{\frac{1-t}{t}}dt <g(x)<2\sqrt{x}$ for all $x \in (0,1)$, then find $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} f(x)g(x)$.

I am looking to multiply the inequality by $f(x)$ and then apply squeeze theorem but the only problem I can't tackle is what should I put in place of $f(x)$ as $f(x)=\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: Is helpful function $\sqrt{\lfloor \frac{1}{x}\rfloor}$ ?

Comment: @zkutch Although using your hint, I have got the correct answer which is $2$ but for $f(x)=\sqrt{\lfloor\frac{1}{x}\rfloor}$ , shouldn't $\frac{1}{x} \in [n,n+1)$ but here $\frac{1}{x} \in (n,n+1]$.

Comment: What about $\lceil \frac 1 x \rceil$?

Answer (score 1):

First notice that as $x\to0^+$,
$$\left(f(x)\right)^2=\left\lceil\frac1x\right\rceil-1\to\infty$$
and (by definition of $\lceil~\rceil$)
$$\frac1{\sqrt{1+\frac1{\left(f(x)\right)^2}}}\le f(x)\sqrt x<1$$
hence (by the squeeze theorem)
$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\sqrt xf(x)=1.$$
Let us now estimate $h(x)-h(x^2)$, where
$$h(x):=\int_0^x\sqrt{\frac{1-t}t}dt.$$
By L'Hospital's theorem (N.B. this was the main idea in [@Mathslover's sadly deleted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4879102)),
$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{h(x)}{\sqrt x}=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1-x}x}}{\frac1{2\sqrt x}}=2$$
hence $$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{h(x^2)}{\sqrt x}=0,$$
so that
$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\left(h(x)-h(x^2)\right)f(x)=2$$
and we are done: by the squeeze theorem again,
$$\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)g(x)=2.$$